# Empty slide showing the title of each subsection (beamer Metropolis)

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, beamer-metropolis

I have just a simple question about the beamer template Metropolis.

I would like to have an empty slide showing the title of each subsection (exactly as for the section).

How can I do that?

Thanks !

Comment: Please always include a small, but compilable test file in your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `subsectionpage` option to enable title pages for subsections:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[subsectionpage=progressbar]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\begin{document}

\section{Section name}
\subsection{Subsection name}
\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]